# Specify multiple constraints on a type (Scala)

Tags: scala, types

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
abstract class DbFinder[T <: PublicKey with Null]
```

but when I try to return an object of type T as null, it fails to compile. Previously I had:

```
abstract class DbFinder[T >: Null]
```

which happily let me return null.

I assume I've got a bit confused with the first line of code. I want to insist that T extends PublicKey but also that T can be nullable. How do I do this?

Regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the best way is to use an Option, so you can use None to simulate null passing:

```
abstract class DbFinder{def someMethod(a: Option[PublicKey]): Any = ...}
```

In your code the Null constraint is redundant because every Scala reference type inherits from Null, so you are simply stating you expect a PublicKey subclass instance.

And, by the way, you should avoid use of null in Scala, as I stated above.

Comment: No, Null is a sub type of all reference types. Nothing is a subtype of all types.

Comment: Thought the same thing when I saw PublicKey with Null, kind of redundant isnt't it? :)

Comment: Well we're trying to "get" stuff that is identifiable by ID. So, if you make the query and return nothing, then you need to handle that somehow)

Comment: Yes, you have to match on input value, if you need I can expand the code to include that... @RichOliver I'm going to edit the answer as per your further info, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
abstract class DbFinder[T >: Null <: PublicKey]
```

Using `Null` as an upper bound doesn't help, because `Nothing` is the default lower bound, and `Nothing` can't be `null`.